# Passing Encoded Points Causes unterminated string literal Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

I am having performance issues on map with a lot of polygons and after a bit of research I discovered this PHP implementation of Google's encoding algorithm:

http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/PolylineEncoder.php.txt

I ran the script on my database of long/lat coords (a string) and created a new column for each polygon with the encoded value.

I then wrote a script to output the JavaScript to create the overlays per the API.

```
var tr_27019090602 = new GPolyline.fromEncoded({
  color: "#0000ff",
  weight: 4,
  opacity: 0.8,
  points: '}w~pGrm~yPU|JCfATKrAy@fAy@|BaBt@i@n@e@rCyBDCl@[TMpAc@NG`BW~@?r@?`CAvHTrHPbA@dDF`@?jA@hCB|DBxDBz@?B}DFiGBcE@w@@wCPqCT_AZu@f@s@X_@Xg@|AgA~DwCzC_Cx@a@RKt@S~@I@?Di@Fq@Gg@HS@q@q@oEa@{@[Um@sAc@o@Yc@_@MQIo@Bm@SOc@@QBWVy@XSFUKc@Ui@E_@AMF[Vg@Rm@Bw@EsA]iBMmAMu@EWDMRIVUT{@Bu@Km@ESc@iASQq@MqA_Bi@iAYo@IWe@sAk@D@DECgBN_CaCm@eC[oAFgOK}IlBkB_@BWNa@d@EJCHG@A@Yc@Ii@AiBC_ADu@Ng@TYRONWHc@HYi@RQFU?k@HSVq@Rw@?EaG?wC?u@?i@?{CAcJA[?yA?u@?_C?aEAkA?cC?I?E?q@?oA?s@?C?cEAs@?yC?wB?qAAU?u@?aB?G?@rA@pB?BBrF?P?D?x@VhAFZZvA@h@?n@?t@@dC?hF?@NhrA?F@NPrF?vL?hJ??lA?dK?jCEvA?DG`C',
  zoomFactor: 2, 
  numLevels: 18
});
```

I am getting "unterminated string literal" errors, likely because of characters in the encoded string. I tried escaping them but to no avail. I also tried double curly braces.

What can I do to properly pass these in the JavaScript to the API?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the encoded string

Comment: *"I then wrote a script to output the JavaScript "* - showing that would help. As a general rule, pass data through `json_encode` before outputting it for JS consumption.

Comment: Dr Molle is correct in that there's nothing wrong with the encoded string. You can test it here: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/decode.html